# Lazy load module with Router Guard with dynamic routes in Angular4

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular4-router

I have single lazy load module with multiple components having dynamic routes each component define by router guard.So how to configure routes for each component having dynamic routes . For every route path i am able to see the same component and when i route manually using url am getting error "Guard is not a function".

Below is my code:
mycomponent.module.ts

```
@NgModule({

    imports: [
        routing,
        SharedModule,
        CommentsModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
                    MyComponent1,
                    MyComponent2,
                    MyComponent3,
                    MyComponent4,
                    MyComponent5,
    ],
    providers: [mycomponentService]

})
export class MyComponentModule { }
```

---

mycomponent.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: '/my-todos', component: MyComponent1 },
            { path: '/edit-my-todo/:tid', component: MyComponent2 },
            { path: '/edit-my-todo/single-todo/:tid', component: MyComponent2 },
            { path: '/edit-my-todo/multi-todo/:tid', component: MyComponent2 },
            { path: '/add-todo', component: MyComponent3 },
            { path: '/multiple-todo-details/:tid', component: MyComponent4 },
            { path: '/todo/:alias', component: MyComponent5 },
            { path: '/todo-preview/:tid', component: MyComponent5 },
        ]
    },
];
```

---

app.routing.ts

```
 {
    path: '', 
    loadChildren:'app/mycomponent/mycomponent.module#MyComponentModule'   
};
```

How to configure routes for this dynamic routes, even I am facing error of gaurd is not a function. Does anyone know how to configure routes for above. Does anyone face the same issue before. Any help would be great help. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out, the way of configuring the routes. Hope this helps someone in future

mycomponent.routing.ts

```
     const routes: Routes = [
        { path: 'my-todos', component: MyComponent1 },
        { path: 'edit-my-todo/:tid', component: MyComponent2 },
        { path: 'edit-my-todo/single-todo/:tid', component: MyComponent2 },
        { path: 'edit-my-todo/multi-todo/:tid', component: MyComponent2 },
        { path: 'add-todo', component: MyComponent3 },
        { path: 'multiple-todo-details/:tid', component: MyComponent4 },
        { path: 'todo/:alias', component: MyComponent5 },
        { path: 'todo-preview/:tid', component: MyComponent5 },
```

];

app.routing.ts

```
 {
       path: '',
       canActivate: [AuthGuard],
       canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
       children: [
                   { path: '',
                     loadChildren: 
                     'app/mycomponent/mycomponent.module#MyComponentModule' 
                   },
                ],
  }
```

This is working fine and works well.